# Converting a list to an array with ToArray()

Tags: c#, list, error-handling, type-conversion, toarray

I've created a class called listItem and the following list:

```
List<listItem> myList = new List<listItem>();
```

At some point in my code, I want to convert it to an array, thereby using:

```
listItem[] myArray = myList.ToArray();
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, and I get this error message:

```
Cannot convert [...] listItem[] to [...] List<listItem>
```

I tried to figure this out, but very unsuccessfully...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My bad, the first code line I wrote was indeed mistyped!

Actually, all the code above works pretty well. My error was due to the fact that my function:

```
List<listItem> myFunction()
```

returned myArray, hence the conversion problem... It is now fixed. :)

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: A listitem isn't the same as a list<> ;)

Comment: Your first line won't compile to start with, and the error message suggests a conversion the other way round. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, and the verbatim error message.

Comment: Is that typed in correctly? Your issue seems to have nothing to do with the ToArray() call.

Comment: The error message you've posted relates to converting array of ListItems into List<ListItem>, not the other way around. List<ListItem>.ToArray() should work perfectly fine. Post whole code or whole error message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the error (as pointed out from Darkshadw and Jon Skeet)

```
listItem myList = new List<listItem>();
```

You are assigning the value of a List to a listItem.

Replace it with

```
List<listItem> myList = new List<listItem>();
```

to create a list of listItem. Then

```
listItem[] myArray = myList.ToArray();
```

will work.

Comment: How to give size?

Comment: To get size: `myArray.size`. To set: `myArray = new Array[5];` but deletes old array

Comment: It works. `ToArray()` on a `List` converts the list to array depending on the type. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried

```
listItem[] myArray = myList.ToArray(new listItem[]{});
```

in Java it works, im not sure in c#

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] s = myList.ToArray();
```

Considering myList is list of string